# How do you animate table rows using ng-animate in the same way as one would list items?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

It's quite simple to smoothly animate lists using angular's ng-animate, but tables seem to be another story.

[Plunker list](http://plnkr.co/edit/CrH9kxTqIUmTUsmnzohI?p=preview)

[Plunker table](http://plnkr.co/edit/bkxmHqn8YCzj85mzICCH?p=preview)

The table move animations don't work, the items just snap into place, I suppose some other CSS/JS is required for the table, but I'm not sure what would work, I tried a lot of things with no success.

I'm sure it's possible, for example there's this [jQuery table animation](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lke2o7cX5Rjto8M883wa?p=preview)

But how does this translate to angular animate? Do I have to delve into some JS/jQuery DOM manipulation through a directive or is there another way?

Either way, I'd like to see an elegant way to do this in angular.

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: I did, but "display: block" overrides the tr default "display: table-row" (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html) and my more complex table crumbles. I tried a few things without success, was going to make another plunker to show what happens, but plunker didn't work at the time. I'll try to get it done soon, perhaps you or someone else knows what's going on. Thank you for the answer though, I think it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Indeed it only works for simple cases (where the default `table-row` display style can be "simulated"with other CSS fixes). Unfortunately, since tables have there unique display style, it is not possible to animate all properties (and this is not something Angular-specific).

Comment: It may be so, perhaps I'll make some custom animation in the future if there's no simple solution. You can see the result of changing display to block here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OMZzCMrUgwCxgKPPjOKU?p=preview - Looking at it makes me think there's a way, though what that is I'm not sure :)

Comment: I see what you mean. Looking t it mkes me think there isn't a way :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `height` of the rows remains constant (until they are removed). In order for the `height` of the rows to become animatable you need to apply to them: `display: block;`

```
.animate-repeat: {
    ...
    display: block;
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/k6UDLhlYWOGnClzY6f39?p=preview)**.

Comment: This does work, this however unfortunately removes the table grid formatting, which is why one would use a table in the first place lol

Comment: @RedactedProfile: True :) It's not meant as a generic solution, but rather targeted against OP's specific usecase. Animating tables is a pain unfortunately (it should be avoided as much as possible).